# How to get xml data from url in wordpress loop?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I am trying to display xml data in wordpress recents topics loop. I tried this but its not showing the same output in every article.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://www.mywebsite.com/count.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

                    foreach($xml->counts as $counts)
{
echo $counts->ss . "<br>";
}
```

XML FILE:

```
<gizcounts>

  <counts>
   <lkid>1</lkid>
   <sid>1</sid>
   <ss>0</ss>
 </counts>

 <counts>
   <lkid>2</lkid>
   <sid>3</sid>
   <ss>44</ss>
 </counts>

  <counts>
   <lkid>3</lkid>
   <sid>2</sid>
   <ss>35</ss>
 </counts>

</gizcounts>
```

I want to know how to get that xml data in wordpress loop.

Comment: what is the output for print_r($xml->counts); ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$xml->children()
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_children.asp

In this case

```
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("http://www.mywebsite.com/count.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

                foreach($xml->children() as $counts)


  {
echo $counts->ss . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Its showing all the xml data of ss. I want to show $xml->counts[0]->ss to first article, then $xml->counts[1]->ss to second article.

Comment: can you show your article loop ? maybe past your full code.. I think you have to combine loops.

Comment: I am using simple wordpress loop <?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
 while ( have_posts() ) {
  the_post(); 
  //
  // Post Content here
  //
 } // end while
} // end if
?>     in post content I want to display that xml data

Comment: Try this 
 <?php
   $xml=simplexml_load_file("http://www.mywebsite.com/count.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

                foreach($xml->children() as $counts)


  {


 if ( have_posts() ) 
{ while ( have_posts() ) 
{

 the_post(); 
echo $counts->ss . "<br>";
// // Post Content here // }
 // end while }
 // end if 

} 
?>